# How can I separte a Cell Value into Multiple Cells (Name, Street, City, State, Zip)

Tags: vba, excel, split, formula

Cell `A1` contains the following text:

```
John Smith
2201 Test ST
Test City, CA Test Zip
```

How can I put the

- John Smith in `A2`,
- 2201 Test ST in `A3`,
- Test City in `A4`,
- CA in `A5`
- and Test Zip in `A6`

?

Comment: It is impossible to replicate your result. You need a common denominator (eg space `' ' `)

Comment: Basically, there is no replicable algorithm for splitting the `Test City`, `CA` and `Test Zip` separately while maintaining functionality for the first two

Comment: If your text's structure will always be like the example, maybe you could split by vbnewline (which gives you `array(0 to 2)`), then split `array(2)` on the last comma (use `strreverse()` if necessary) to get the zip code (this gives you `array(2)(0)` and `array(2)(1)`). If the state will always be a 2 letter code, you could use `left()` on `array(2)(1)`, or split `array(2)(1)` by the first space only. This approach makes assumptions about the structure of your data. But might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the items always separated by spaces you could use:

```
=left(a1,find(" ",a1,find(" ",a1,1)+1)-1)
```

Which works as follows: find gets the position of the first space, then the second find starts at that position plus 1, so left has the position of the second space minus one to give the full name.

Then you can also use mid() and right() to cut out the other bits. You may have to deal with names that have 3 parts etc...